# How do I pull username data from Mongodb and display on Navbar

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am new to mongoDB and most things programming wise but one requirement in my last project is to show the name of the user in the right hand corner of my pages. I tried to use

```
import Db = require("mongodb/lib/db");

function NavBar(){

  function findName() {
    const name = db.users.find({name:brit});
    return name;
  }

  return(

    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">BadBank</a>
      <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#/CreateAccount/">Create Account</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#/login/">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#/deposit/">Deposit</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#/withdraw/">Withdraw</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#/balance/">Balance</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#/alldata/">AllData</a>
          </li>          
        </ul>
      </div>
      Welcome findName();
    </nav>
});
```

but that makes the app break and also VS is giving me a error saying it cannot find that module. I did not add it on top but I am guessing its needed for the db.users.find.

Here is my DAL which I am unsure of is relevant but I figure you may need to know how the information is stored.

```
 // create user account
function create(name, email, password){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const collection = db.collection('users');
        const doc = {name, email, password, balance: 0};
        collection.insertOne(doc, {w:1}, function(err, result) {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(doc);
        });    
    })
}

// find user account
function find(email){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .find({email: email})
            .toArray(function(err, docs) {
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(docs);
        });    
    })
}

// find user account
function findOne(email){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .findOne({email: email})
            .then((doc) => resolve(doc))
            .catch((err) => reject(err));    
    })
}`


` // create user account
function create(name, email, password){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const collection = db.collection('users');
        const doc = {name, email, password, balance: 0};
        collection.insertOne(doc, {w:1}, function(err, result) {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(doc);
        });    
    })
}

// find user account
function find(email){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .find({email: email})
            .toArray(function(err, docs) {
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(docs);
        });    
    })
}

// find user account
function findOne(email){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .findOne({email: email})
            .then((doc) => resolve(doc))
            .catch((err) => reject(err));    
    })
}
```

I have searched for a couple hours trying to find a solution and may have to settle for the use of cookies and or sessions but I do not think that is what the project is asking for.

Comment: Maybe it is an oversite but you imported the library as "Db" instead of "db"

Comment: Hmm interestingly enough this is something VS code added in for me but I will try that.